# pull sharepoint 2013 external rss view

Tags: web-part, rss

how to pull sharepoint 2013 external rss view webpart data to a list?
is there any way to Achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPServices to read the RSS feed, parse its fields using XML and insert into list again using SPServices.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this in my company by following this example. Let me know if you are facing any problem

[knock-out rss feeder](https://github.com/melnor/Knockout-RSS-Feeder/blob/master/Index.html)